# How to do faster XOR operation with decimal number without converting to binary?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, xor

how can I do XOR operation of numbers like 7 XOR 3, 8 XOR 11, etc? Faster without converting them into binary numbers.? Is there any way?/

Comment: Do you mean by hand?

Comment: Yes.. of course.

Comment: Not really. Memorization is possible. And if you can recognize that `A AND B = 0` (in some cases that is easy, eg `16 XOR 5`), then it may be simpler to mentally compute `A + B` which in that case (but not in general) would be equal to `A XOR B`.